# Inertia.js + Vue 3 + SSR: Data redefined when rendering in the browser

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

I'm using Inertia.js + Vue 3 for Server-Side Rendering (SSR). In certain cases, I want to pre-fetch and set data during server-side rendering.

```
<template>
  data: {{myData}}
</template>
<script setup>
import {ref} from "vue";

const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined'
const myData = ref(null)

if (isServer) {
  console.log('on server')
  myData.value = 'data from server'
} else {
  console.log('on client')
  if (myData.value === null) {
    myData.value = 'data is null'
  }
}
</script>
```

Both console logs are visible. However, in the browser, `myData` initially displays as `'Data from the server'` but quickly changes to `'Data is null'`. When I check the page source, `myData` is rendered as `'Data from the server'`.

Does this mean that the `const myData` gets redefined as `null` when the browser renders the page? Is this normal behavior, and does it imply that prefetching data while rendering on the server is not possible?

My expectation is that if the page is rendered on the client, it should display skeletons and perform a partial reload. But if the page is rendered on the server, it should fully render without a partial reload.

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Data: {{ isServer ? 'data from server' : myData }}</p>
    <button v-if="!isServer" @click="partialReload">Partial Reload</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue';

  const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined';
  const myData = ref(null);

  if (!isServer && myData.value === null) {
    myData.value = 'data is null';
  }

  function partialReload() {
    // Implement your partial reload logic here
    // For example, you can use location.reload() to reload the page partially
    location.reload();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. But still, myData initially displays as 'Data from the server' and quickly changes to 'Data is null'. Upon inspecting the page source, it indeed shows 'data ifrom server' The server rendering is behaving as expected, but it seems that myData is being redefined as null in the browser, triggering the condition if (!isServer && myData.value === null).